# Not able to download software from ubuntu software center

Tags: software-center

I am trying to download a software from ubuntu software center and I am getting the following screen.

[image]

If I click on use this source I get

[image]

Thats all, the software does not get installed. Apparently this is happening to all the softwares in Ubuntu software center.

Output of `sudo apt-get update`

```
Err http://in.old-releases.ubuntu.com utopic InRelease
Err http://in.old-releases.ubuntu.com utopic Release.gpg                       
  Could not resolve 'in.old-releases.ubuntu.com'
Ign http://dl.google.com stable InRelease                                      
Hit http://dl.google.com stable Release.gpg                                    
Hit http://dl.google.com stable Release                                        
Ign http://extras.ubuntu.com utopic InRelease                                  
Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com utopic InRelease                                 
Hit http://dl.google.com stable/main i386 Packages                             
Hit http://extras.ubuntu.com utopic Release.gpg                                
Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com utopic Release.gpg                               
Hit http://extras.ubuntu.com utopic Release                                    
Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com utopic Release                                   
Hit http://extras.ubuntu.com utopic/main Sources                               
Ign http://dl.google.com stable/main Translation-en_IN                         
Ign http://dl.google.com stable/main Translation-en                            
Hit http://extras.ubuntu.com utopic/main i386 Packages                         
Ign http://extras.ubuntu.com utopic/main Translation-en_IN                     
Ign http://extras.ubuntu.com utopic/main Translation-en                        
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net utopic InRelease               
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty InRelease   
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty InRelease                            
Get:1 http://ppa.launchpad.net utopic InRelease [15.5 kB]                
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net utopic InRelease                                  
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty InRelease                                  
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net utopic InRelease                                  
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty InRelease                                  
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty InRelease                                  
Err http://archive.ubuntu.com utopic/main i386 Packages                        
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.23 80]
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net utopic Release.gpg                                
Err http://archive.ubuntu.com utopic/universe i386 Packages                    
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.23 80]
Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com utopic/main Translation-en_IN                    
Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com utopic/main Translation-en                       
Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com utopic/universe Translation-en_IN                
Get:2 http://ppa.launchpad.net utopic/main i386 Packages [8,542 B]             
Get:3 http://ppa.launchpad.net utopic/main Translation-en [3,070 B]            
Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com utopic/universe Translation-en                   
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net utopic Release.gpg                                
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net utopic Release.gpg                                
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty Release.gpg                                
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net utopic Release                                    
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main i386 Packages                         
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main Translation-en                        
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main i386 Packages                         
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main Translation-en                        
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net utopic Release                                    
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main i386 Packages                         
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main Translation-en                        
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net utopic Release                                    
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty Release                                    
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main i386 Packages                         
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main Translation-en                        
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net utopic/main i386 Packages                         
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net utopic/main Translation-en                        
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net utopic/main i386 Packages                         
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net utopic/main Translation-en                        
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main i386 Packages                         
Err http://ppa.launchpad.net utopic/main i386 Packages                         
  404  Not Found
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net utopic/main Translation-en_IN                     
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net utopic/main Translation-en                        
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main Translation-en_IN                     
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main Translation-en                        
Fetched 27.1 kB in 21s (1,279 B/s)                                             
Reading package lists... Done
W: Failed to fetch http://in.old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/utopic/InRelease  
W: Failed to fetch http://in.old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/utopic/Release.gpg  Could not resolve 'in.old-releases.ubuntu.com'
W: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/utopic/main/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.23 80]
W: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/utopic/universe/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.23 80]
W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/inameiname/stable/ubuntu/dists/utopic/main/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found
W: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

output of `cat /etc/*release`

```
DISTRIB_ID=Ubuntu
DISTRIB_RELEASE=14.10
DISTRIB_CODENAME=utopic
DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="Ubuntu 14.10"
NAME="Ubuntu"
VERSION="14.10 (Utopic Unicorn)"
ID=ubuntu
ID_LIKE=debian
PRETTY_NAME="Ubuntu 14.10"
VERSION_ID="14.10"
HOME_URL="http://www.ubuntu.com/"
SUPPORT_URL="http://help.ubuntu.com/"
BUG_REPORT_URL="http://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/"
```

Comment: Open the terminal and enter `sudo apt-get update` and edit your post to include the output from that command.

Comment: done, kindly check

Comment: I think I may know what it is... How about, this time, back in the terminal enter `uname -a` and edit your post with that information.

Comment: done, see the edited post

Comment: Oops... Sorry `cat /etc/*release` ;-) My bad - I need to know the version.

Comment: done, see the edited post

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/31083/discussion-between-kgiii-and-penta).

Comment: Don't add "solved" to your title. Accept an answer or write answer. ;)

Comment: i am not able to write an anwer, please kindly re read my edited post

Comment: i was able to post my answer now, maybe some problem from site

Answer (score 3):

[image: EOL for Ubuntu]

As you can see, your version is EOL (End Of Life). After our discussion, in chat, it has been determined that you're going to download 14.04 and install, preserving the `/home` partition. To download 14.04 click [here](http://www.ubuntu.com/download).

Comment: hey, I found out a completely working solution, please see my edit, as your answer does not correctly answer my question I have unticked from answer, but since it was slightly useful I have upvoted it, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

I actually found out the solution to my problem. I was using Ubuntu 14.10 which reached its EOL, so I had to upgrade my ubuntu just to install any software.

There is an ALTERNATIVE WAY , instead of upgrading the OS, just follow the instructions in this link https://superuser.com/a/339572 to edit the sources.list file. After that I was able to install any software from ubuntu software center.

Comment: If I'm reading that properly, you'll only be getting the updates until it was EOL or not much further and newer security updates won't be included. I may be reading that wrong but that *might* be something to consider.